# Positioning the top attribute of a element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having an annoying issue trying to position the responsive navigation hamburger. I am using a plugin called responsive menu which creates the hamburger and uses absolute positioning.

I am trying to position the hamburger in the centre of the header at all times.
To achieve this I am using the following jQuery code.

However, the issue I have is when the hamburger is displayed and you scroll down the page and scroll back to the top of the page quickly. The hamburger does not position itself in the centre of the header. You need to scroll back down slightly for it to jump into place.

Any ideas how I can fix this please.. It's driving me crazy and I don't know jquery very well :(

Thank you for any advice in advance :)

[Link to the site in question](http://176.32.230.52/stratusassociates.co.uk/about-us/)

```
$( window ).on("load resize scroll", function(e){
  var headerHeight = $('nav').height()/2;
  var iconHeight = $('#click-menu').height()/2;
  var total = headerHeight - iconHeight;
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 1) {
  $('#click-menu').css('top', total);
  }
  else {
      $('#click-menu').css('top', total);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard for me to test and confirm this, but I believe the reason it's position is off when it hits the top is because the evaluation of `$('nav').height()/2;` happens immediately, but the header animates to size over 300 ms.

Although a bit hacky, I think you can solve the problem by adding a `setTimeout`

```js
function setNavTop(){
    var headerHeight = $('nav').height()/2;
    var iconHeight = $('#click-menu').height()/2;
    var total = headerHeight - iconHeight;
    $('#click-menu').css('top', total);
}

$( window ).on("load resize scroll", function(e){

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 1) {
        setNavTop();
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(setNavTop, 300); // wait for header to animate to size.
    }
});
```

Since it has to delay for 300ms before adjusting the icon, its looks a bit glitchy. You can improve this by adding tweening the setTimeout. Not the most elegant, but it works

```
setNavTop();
setTimeout(setNavTop, 100);
setTimeout(setNavTop, 200);
setTimeout(setNavTop, 300);
```